Can a website serve only a subset of glyphs from a font, instead of the entire a font, on loading?
There's this Quartz article on how Chinese fonts are made with this curious claim:

This has been possible for a number of years, but Chinese always posed a particular problem: with so many glyphs, the fonts require huge downloads for users that have not visited the site before, putting a strain on bandwidth both for user and provider. (A Chinese font can run up to 6 or 7 megabytes for a single style and weight. Compare that to PT Serif—Quartz’s body font, which covers over 100 Latin languages—which is just 1.4 megabytes for four styles.) Now Chinese webfont providers cleverly scan through a webpage’s text to identify which glyphs are required, and send only those to the user instead of all 13,000-plus.

Is it possible for a website to serve only part of a font to render text? How do browsers download these incomplete fonts? And does it relate to font subsetting with unicode-range?

They do not claim the browser only downloads part of a font. They claim the "server" only offers part of a font.

@DanielB That's the part I'm not really clear on. What does it mean to share part of a font? It's a file right? How's a file any usable if you only have part of it?


What does it mean to share part of a font? It's a file right? How's a file any usable if you only have part of it?

For one, that's not necessarily true; many file types are not "all or nothing" – usually they consist of smaller independent parts, and only have certain parts mandatory (headers or indices) while the rest is "as needed"; many formats are even explicitly designed to be usable in parts. For example, your browser can already begin displaying .html files before they're fully loaded, and it can stream .mp4 video files by downloading just the index and the byte ranges it needs.
But usually font subsetting is done by generating a new file. How do you share part of a photo or some other image? You load/decode the file using an image editing program, crop the part you need and save/reencode it as a new image file. In this way, you don't have "part of a file"; you have a whole file that represents part of the data, but still has a whole structure (scaffolding).
The same can be applied to font files. They have a well-defined structure with clear relationships between parts, so it's possible for font editing software to load a .ttf file, discard unneeded parts such as the individual glyph drawings, and save the rest as a whole new .ttf (or more commonly .woff) font file.
For automated processing this could be done using something like python-fonttools, either by preparing the subset font files upfront like any other asset, or on the fly (a webapp that serves subset fonts just like it could serve cropped images). For example, the Google Fonts API serves subsets by glyph range.
(If you wanted to edit a font file manually, the equivalent of Photoshop might be FontForge. I've used it a few times to delete specific unwanted ligature glyphs from fonts.)

Are you suggesting a web page works the same as PDFs, without room for all the font fallbacks specified in the CSS?

Most web pages don't work this way. They might use statically defined broad subsets that cut the font up by script (Latin vs Greek, etc) or by some other Unicode range.
The post you've quoted specifically describes precise PDF-style subsetting as a novel thing that Chinese webfont providers do in contrast to most "Western" websites which don't do so.
Is it true that there are webfont providers that do so? I don't know. Is it plausible that there are webfont providers that do so? Yes, it's technically possible with existing tools, especially for websites where content is mostly static.
(Although I'd assume it wouldn't be per-page, but rather a fixed subset of "all glyphs used in all articles", as delivering a separate subset for each page would use more data rather than less.)

What if the page content dynamically changes with user interaction, like say, an input field for example?

One would assume that websites that use custom fonts won't be doing this kind of subsetting – or won't be using custom fonts for input fields. It's very common to use a webfont only for body text while forms are left to just whatever the default is. (It's also common to use fancy webfonts only for headings while body text uses a default font; such sites could definitely take advantage of precise subsetting, since the subsets would be small and input fields definitely wouldn't be using a <h1> font.)
(The point being, that the use of a technology is also not an "all or nothing" matter. If a technology is unsuitable for some websites it may still be suitable for others.)
For that matter, I've also seen more than a few Western websites use font subsets that are limited to more-or-less ASCII only (cheapest to license?), which is particularly noticeable when the font is used to display people's names – i.e. the designers did not care about the possibility of a customer's name having characters outside of the basic set, and used it anyway.

I see. My knowledge on how subset fonts are generated "on the fly" and "server-side" isn't much since I have no access to any provider. If the website is self-hosted, the subsetting method is usually manual and predetermined, for example by using tools like everythingfonts.com/subsetter or サブセットフォントメーカー. I wonder how western web font providers do their providing. Do they usually give a CSS reference to their server so they can generate subset fonts for you on the fly there, the way Google seems to do?

A small correction: the most commonly used format is woff2, and not woff.

"Is it true that there are webfont providers that do so?" It's true. I've stumbled on this Japanese term, 動的なサブセット化, and by Googling its English translation, "Dynamic Subsetting," I found out that Adobe offers this capability. If Adobe has had this for so long before (they do offer CJK fonts), it's safe to say East Asian providers have done the same.
